# Python seaborn legends cut off

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, matplotlib, seaborn

The figure resulting from the Python code below unfortunately cuts off part of the legends. How can I avoid this? Did I miss a parameter in the `sns` call or is this due to how I've set up my PyCharm IDE?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('gm_2008_region.csv')
df = df.drop('Region', axis=1)
plt.figure()
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), square=True, cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.show()
```

This is the resulting figure:
[image: Figure]

The .csv file can be found [here](https://github.com/apitsch/datasets/blob/master/gm_2008_region.csv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.28)` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('gm_2008_region.csv')
df = df.drop('Region', axis=1)
plt.figure()
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), square=True, cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.28)
plt.show()
```

Giving you:

[image: image plot]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change the `figsize` of `plt.figure` such as...

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('gm_2008_region.csv')
df = df.drop('Region', axis=1)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.heatmap(df.corr(), square=True, cmap='RdYlGn')
plt.show()
```

[image]